# I think Wordpress is blocking me on Google - and I don't even use Wordpress now, but the 'discourage' box remains?

Tags: search-engines

I started to build a site on Wordpress using my hostgator account because it was offered, I also created a Wordpress account through that. But it didn't work out, so I deleted my log in, and went on to build my site in dreamweaver and upload it. But, when I was using Wordpress I think I checked the box that said to 'discourage search engines from indexing'. Now, even though I don't even have a Wordpress site or a log in, I can't be found on the internet. How do I reverse that? Not only that, when I google my url, which happens to be my name nothing comes up, not my instagram, fb, etc. all sites that use my name are blocked!

Answer (score 2):

The only thing the "discourage search engines from indexing" checkbox did was add a `noindex` tag to the header of your WordPress site. If you're not using WordPress anymore that tag isn't there anymore and it cannot have any effect. Any solution to the issue you're experiencing now will not involve WordPress, so there's not much more that can be said here.

Comment: Thank you Jacob. Maybe it's on Hostgator's end - they just started offering Wordpress (used right through their portal) it's integrated with them somehow - maybe there is a noindex file hiding on the server there... I'll contact their admin!